# How to prevent image distortion in wide monitors?

Tags: css, image

The monitor I work on is 16 inches and I have a list of circular images with `border-radius: 50%;` that are aligned horizontally. To avoid losing the quality of the images, I have kept the original size of the images which is 500x500(px) but I want the width and height to be maximum 150px.

In 19 inch and wider monitors these round images are shown as ovals with distorted width.

Here is the css code of the images. Is there any way that I can avoid this deformation? Any help is appreciated.

```
.circular img {
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't set height? Have you tried setting also `height: 150px; width: 150px;`? Also it will lose more quality when re-sizing in CSS than in image processing program (like photoshop)

Comment: No, I have not set the height. Also, as I am checking, the image loses drastic quality in Photoshop and Illustrator than in css.